# find if data existed 6 months ago ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS report builder I am trying to write an expression for calculated fields in my dataset to see if this data exists now, existed 6 months ago, and existed a year ago. (So 3 different calculated fields).
I don't want to use different datasets as the information all needs to go into a table with a percentage change column.

I have the from and to dates of the data and have been trying to write something along the lines of

```
=IIF(Fields!From.Value<-6months AND Fields!To.Value>-6months, true, false)
```

I'm obviously missing something in my expression but my knowledge in this is limited. Any ideas on how to get this to do what I want it to?

my data basically is this (but being pulled from various tables in our database)

person ID - condition 1 - from date - to date

person ID - condition 2 - from date - to date

person ID - condition 1 - from date - to date

person ID - condition 3 - from date - to date

etc.

I've been asked to make a table with the conditions as the rows, the columns are "exists now", "existed 6 months ago" and "existed 12 months ago" and a count of the person IDs as the data

the from and to fields are date fields

Comment: What data type is `Fields!From.Value`? Also, is this for one textbox in a matrix? Or three different text boxes. More info would be useful in getting a quicker answer... How about implementing logic in your SQL Query?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a sample of your data. I suspect this will be much easier to do in SQL.Also, as @bjones already asked, what datatype are your `from` and `to` fields?

Answer (score 0):

The visibility thing can be a little confusing sometimes, as with everything in SSRS it can be finicky.

Since you're new at this I would recommend something easy like trying to hide your first row. You'll probably want to do this by right clicking the table and going to properties. Under visibility, you can add an expression. Try hiding a row by the unique ID or something like that first...

> =IIF(Fields!UID.Value=1234, TRUE, FALSE)

The reason I say to go through this is to make sure you're able to properly hide a row. If you are using the visibility in groups instead, sometimes it doesn't work expected. Anyway, once you get that working, you'll want to do something like this.

> =IIF( (DateDiff("m", CDate(Fields!FromDate.Value), Now()) < 5 AND DateDiff("m", CDate(Fields!ToDate.Value), Now()) > 5), FALSE, TRUE)

You'll be using the DateDiff function to calculate the difference between the date and NOW() (which returns current date). The "m" specifies you want to know how many months between dates. CDate will cast your field into a DateTime object.